# swift SpriteKit SKNode class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a tile game from a tutorial and it has this bit of code in it:

```
var tile: SKNode?

    switch tileCode {
        case "g":
            tile = SKSpriteNode(texture: atlas?.textureNamed("grassTile"))

        default:
        println("Unknown tilecode: \(tileCode)")
    }
```

I am confused as tile is declared as type SKNode, yet in the switch statement it is made into an SKSpriteNode. Why is it possible to to do this?

Comment: SKSpriteNode is a subclass of SKNode

Answer (score 0):

You will still access `tile` as an SKNode, because it is declared as such, but it will actually point to a `SKSpriteNode` object. The reason this works and the compiler doesn't complain is that `SKSpriteNode` is a subclass of `SKNode`, i.e. it has all the properties and methods that a `SKNode` would have. The whole concept is called [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and strongly related to [dynamic binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding).